# A faster way to build a cumulative tally of DateTime values using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a python pandas dataframe with DateTime values of multiple events Starting & Finishing.I want to build a tally of all the times a certain datetime (down to the nearest minute) is between the start and finish datetimes of the events.  I use a dictionary to build the tally, then create into a dataframe, removing the date components and summing up all the tallys by time field.

I have the following code, which works, but i'm finding with a larger dataframe (1000s rows rather than 100s) the processing time is too slow to the point of useless. I'm usually a fan of vectorisation but can't seem to get it working with this problem.

Working code (but slow):

```
# Creating the dataframe
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

data = {"Date":[date(2024,1,5),date(2024,1,6),date(2024,1,7)],"Start":[pd.Timestamp("2024-01-05 10:05"),pd.Timestamp("2024-01-06 09:05"),pd.Timestamp("2024-01-07 11:12")],"Finish":[pd.Timestamp("2024-01-05 10:35"),pd.Timestamp("2024-01-06 09:55"),pd.Timestamp("2024-01-07 11:58")]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Creating the Date range
dates = pd.date_range(start=df["Date"].min(), end=df["Date"].max(),freq="1min")

#Dictionary of dates to store the cummulative score
d_data = {}

for x in dates:
    d_data[x] = 0
```

This next code, iterating by line I want to improve on, to gain a speed performance.

```
#Iterating by each line of the df and through the stored dates
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    for d in dates:
        if (d >= row[1]) & (d <= row[2]):
            d_data[d] += 1
```

Then using the dictionary to create a dataframe

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(index=d_data.keys(),data=d_data.values(),columns=["Count"])
df_data.reset_index(names="Date",inplace=True)

# Removing the date component to just leave the time and sum each occurance
df_data["Date"] = df_data["Date"].dt.time
df_data["Date"] = df_data["Date"].astype("str")
df_data["Date"] = df_data["Date"].str[:-3]

df_data = df_data.groupby("Date").sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   | Date  | Count 
0  | 00:00 | 0
1  | 00:01 | 0

545| 09:05 | 1
546| 09:06 | 1
```

Comment: Are you sure `&` is the correct operator here?  Shouldn't it be `and`?

Comment: Thanks for help so far. Question edited for sample of dataframe & expected out. The ampersand works well, but and also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# count the number of occurrences for each minute
date_ranges_list = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    date_range = pd.date_range(start=row["Start"], end=row["Finish"], freq="1min")
    date_ranges_list.append(pd.Series(date_range))
all_date_ranges = pd.concat(date_ranges_list)
minute_counts = all_date_ranges.value_counts().sort_index()

# if you want, you can add rows with zero
all_dates = pd.Series(
    0, index=pd.date_range(start=df["Date"].min(), end=df["Date"].max(), freq="1min")
)
minute_counts = all_dates.add(minute_counts, fill_value=0)

# convert to dataframe
out = minute_counts.to_frame(name="Count")
```

Result:

```
                     Count
2024-01-05 00:00:00    0.0
2024-01-05 00:01:00    0.0
2024-01-05 00:02:00    0.0
2024-01-05 00:03:00    0.0
2024-01-05 00:04:00    0.0
...                    ...
2024-01-07 11:54:00    1.0
2024-01-07 11:55:00    1.0
2024-01-07 11:56:00    1.0
2024-01-07 11:57:00    1.0
2024-01-07 11:58:00    1.0
```

Comment: Thanks e-motta. So if I understand correctly, rather than my method of iterating each row through another iteration of each 1min datetime to tally matches, you have created a list of the 1mins between the start & finish for each row, then used value counts to build a frequency these values. I'm not sure what the pd.concat to the date_range_list does however. I haven't seen the series.add() before so thank you.

Comment: For each row (event) in the original `df`, I'm creating a `date_range` with `freq=1min`, converting it into a `pd.Series`, and appending it to a temporary list `date_ranges_list`. Then I concatenate all these series into a single series using `pd.concat` and store it in `all_date_ranges`. Each row of `all_date_ranges` represents 1 min of the original  events, so we count the occurrence of each minute using `.value_counts()` and store it in `minute_counts`.

Comment: If you need the rows with the minutes where no events happened (i.e., count == 0), you can use the second part (`all_dates ...`).

Comment: Finally, the resulting series is converted into a dataframe with a column `Count`.

Comment: I hope that's clear now. This should be significantly faster than your original approach, as it avoids iterating over the entire `dates` range for every event in the original `df`.

Comment: Yes, that very clear, thank you. I hadn't considered that method. Its considerable faster and means I can repeat this using a greater date range, which is really helpful. Cheers.